# The ratio between positive/negative numbers

Tags: probability, ratio

I am creating a model that compares multiple data points of two attributes and compares them vs one another as a percentage of 100.

So for instance, comparing the values A=1.24 v B=0.44 would be:

100/(A+B)*A = 73.81%
100/(A+B)*B = 26.19%

However, one of the data points sometimes has negative numbers and I am looking for a formula to compare them in the same way; is this possible? 
I can compare +/+ and -/- using the above method, but it doesn't work using +/-.

Would I have to use the difference between the two numbers as a regulator? If so, I am not sure how.

So an example of the formula I would like to work out would be:

A=1.04 v B=-0.32 as a percentage of 100.

Thanks for any help - I have no formal mathematics tuition so please forgive any naivety!

Comment: Are you trying to build a computer model?

Comment: If you take $A+B$ as $100 \%$, your formula will still work as the percentages will sum up to $100$. You can run into a problem if $A+B=0$ though. Can you explain in more detail what are you trying to model?

Comment: The best solution is likely to depend on where these numbers come from, what they actually mean, and most importantly what you’re going to do with the result of your comparison formula. For many applications you actually _want_ negative numbers when the data are trending in a particular way.

Comment: I am building a sports model that compares golfers statistics. Most of the data points for both players are positive numbers, eg driving distance/finishing position. The data point I need to compare is players scores to par, for instance Player A's average score is 1.04 over par and Player B's is -0.32

Comment: In that case par is a rather meaningless number to compare with.  Maybe you should use raw score instead of relative to par.  Then all the numbers are positive.  You need to think about what you want the formula to do, then find the formula.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your formula.  It will give a percentage greater than $100$ for the positive one and less than $0$ for the negative one.  There is sense to this.  If you think of two divisions of a company and ask what fraction of the company profit is contributed by each, if one makes more than the whole company while the other makes a loss this is what you will get.  If both make losses, the percentages will show which division contributed most to the loss.

In your example $A=1.04, B=-0.32$ the total profit is $0.72$ and $A$ contributed about $144\%$ of that while $B$ contributed about $-44\%$

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on how you're comparing the two numbers.

If you want, you can compare them using $$\frac{|A|}{|A|+|B|}\times100\%$$ where the vertical bars indicates absolute value.

I just want to point out that 'comparing' numbers in this way is really, really sketchy and I can't imagine many circumstances under which it would be useful. A more natural thing to do would be e.g $$X=\frac{\left||A|-|B|\right|}{|A|}\times100\%$$

whence you can say that $B$ is $X%$ more/less than $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I am building a sports model that compares golfers statistics. Most of the data points for both players are positive numbers, eg driving distance/finishing position. The data point I need to compare is players scores to par, for instance Player A's average score is 1.04 over par and Player B's is 0.32 below par